# Titanium iOS: Anything wrong with a global navgroup?

Tags: ios, navigation, titanium

Currently when making an ios app in Titanium, I have to pass the navgroup into all windows.
That means always passing the navgroup through the entire function call stacks to the part where a window is launched.

```
function launchAboutWindow(mynavgroup)
{
var window = TI.UI.createWindow({navgroup: mynavgroup});
}
```

Since it's always the same anyway, is would it be bad practice to simply have a GLOBAL navgroup? instead of passing navgroup contexts all over the place?

```
function launchAboutWindow()
{
var window = TI.UI.createWindow({navgroup: GLOBALNAVGROUP});
}
```

What would be the negative consequence of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the thing about Global variables, is that they always remain in memory, and are not being cleaned by the garbage collector. That's why it's good practice to avoid putting stuff on the global scope.

Of course, to every rule there is an exception. In my opinion, since you are passing the reference around anyhow, you are keeping that object (and it's reference) alive. In my opinion it would only make sense to keep that sort of thing global - even just to make your code more maintainable - which is not less important than keeping it right.

I wouldn't do that for every object - each case on it's own.

BTW - in Alloy, there is a special namespace Titanium has for global object (don't abuse it either!).

Also, I recommend looking at the cross platform navigation controller:

http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2013/08/a-cross-platform-navigation-group/

http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/08/forging-titanium-episode-2-a-cross-platform-navigation-controller/

https://github.com/vuinguyen/Ti-Navigation-Controller

Comment: When we first had this problem, we used a Global Variable for the NavigationWindow but we re-implemented this for a new project last week and instead of using a global, we passed the navwin as an argument to the child controller then called openWindow on that.  I'm not sure if that is better or worse than global navigation? Any idea? Also for Android implementation of a NavigationWindow, we're using the solution here: http://fokkezb.nl/2013/10/21/cross-platform-ui/ works well.